modem device not detected by mmcli command
I have an old Qualcomm-based Venus mobile cellular modem. I attempted to get it working on my Linux machine by following the instructions on arch wiki page.
What I have done: install usb_modeswitch package, replug the modem device, load option kernel module, create /dev/ttyUSB* device node using usb_serial kernel module, check the device with lsusb command and check the device with mmcli command:
[root@ASUS reyuki]#  lsmod | grep option
option                 61440  0
usb_wwan               28672  1 option
[root@ASUS reyuki]#  echo 1d09 aef4  >/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
[root@ASUS reyuki]#  lsusb -vt
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/5p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
        |__ Port 002: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 18f8:1686 [Maxxter]
        |__ Port 002: Dev 004, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 18f8:1686 [Maxxter]
        |__ Port 003: Dev 006, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
        |__ Port 003: Dev 006, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
        |__ Port 004: Dev 007, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 0406:2814 Fujitsu-ICL Computers
        |__ Port 004: Dev 007, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 0406:2814 Fujitsu-ICL Computers
    |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited
    |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited
    |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited
    |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 3, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited
    |__ Port 004: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 2b7e:b685
    |__ Port 004: Dev 003, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 2b7e:b685
    |__ Port 005: Dev 005, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
        ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks
    |__ Port 005: Dev 005, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
        ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks
    |__ Port 005: Dev 005, If 2, Class=Wireless, Driver=[none], 480M
        ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 003.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
/:  Bus 004.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 005.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
/:  Bus 006.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 007.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
/:  Bus 008.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
[root@ASUS reyuki]#  ls /dev/ttyUSB*
/dev/ttyUSB0  /dev/ttyUSB1  /dev/ttyUSB2
[root@ASUS reyuki]#  mmcli -S
successfully requested to scan devices
[root@ASUS reyuki]#  mmcli -L
No modems were found

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

    |__ Port 001: Dev 028, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited
    |__ Port 001: Dev 028, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited
    |__ Port 001: Dev 028, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited        
    |__ Port 001: Dev 028, If 3, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 12M
        ID 1d09:aef4 TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited

This part of the lsusb -vt output indicates the device is providing interfaces in addition to the USB-storage interface, so the usb_modeswitch either has done its job or is not required for this device.
You have since then managed to load the generic USB serial driver, but it doesn't seem to help much. As a wild guess, try adding the ID to the option USB-serial sub-driver instead: it already recognizes a huge list of USB mobile cellular modems, and if yours is a rebranded version of one of those, with luck adding the ID might be all that's needed.
Since you already added the ID to the generic sub-driver, you would have to unload the driver to undo that. So either run modprobe -r usbserial or reboot, and then load the option sub-driver (modprobe option should be sufficient, it will automatically load the main usbserial driver).
Then run:
echo 1d09 aef4  >/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id

After that, if the /dev/ttyUSB[0-2] devices are visible again, run mmcli -S to tell it to scan again.
This is just a wild guess: it might or might not help.
If it doesn't, the output of lsusb -v -d 1d09:aef4 (without the -t option) might help knowledgeable people on the internet to further identify your device, and perhaps figure out the actual device model ("TechFaith Wireless Technology Limited" sounds like OEM rebranding, and you already said it's Qualcomm-based).

looks like you made an answer based on a question I haven't edited yet (the lspci output in your post show the driver still none), I've created /dev/ttyUSB[0-2] and ran mmcli -S to rescan, but mmcli still isn't detecting the modem. here's the lspci output.

Yes, I got the output snippet from the old version. I saw your edit, but did not refresh the snippet yet, as even the old snippet proves what I was talking about, i.e. there are interfaces other than usb-storage available. I see the Driver=usbserial_generic in the newer lsusb -vt output, so the devices are still under the control of the generic USB-serial sub-driver, not the option sub-driver. The option sub-driver is used by many cellular modems and contains code to add the network interface if appropriate; the generic sub-driver won't do that.

Ah yes, my bad didn't read your full post, I've follow your instruction and here's the log you can see the option module loaded on the lsusb output

and dmesg output if needed.
